# STS 3.7 issue for maven compile plugin

Tags: spring, maven, m2eclipse, m2e, m2e-wtp

Today i downloaded STS version 3.7.2 for 64 bit machine. In that i import my maven project and i get below error

```
Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
CoreException: Could not get the value for parameter compilerId for plugin execution default-compile: PluginResolutionException: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.1 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: The following artifacts could not be resolved: org.apache.maven:maven-plugin-api:jar:2.0.9, org.apache.maven:maven-artifact:jar:2.0.9, org.apache.maven:maven-core:jar:2.0.9, org.apache.maven:maven-settings:jar:2.0.9, org.apache.maven:maven-plugin-parameter-documenter:jar:2.0.9, org.apache.maven:maven-profile:jar:2.0.9, org.apache.maven:maven-model:jar:2.0.9, org.apache.maven:maven-repository-metadata:jar:2.0.9, org.apache.maven:maven-error-diagnostics:jar:2.0.9, org.apache.maven:maven-project:jar:2.0.9, org.apache.maven:maven-plugin-registry:jar:2.0.9, org.apache.maven:maven-plugin-descriptor:jar:2.0.9, org.apache.maven:maven-artifact-manager:jar:2.0.9, org.apache.maven:maven-monitor:jar:2.0.9, org.apache.maven:maven-toolchain:jar:1.0, org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-container-default:jar:1.5.5, org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-classworlds:jar:2.2.2: Failure to transfer org.apache.maven:maven-plugin-api:jar:2.0.9 from https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced. Original error: Could not transfer artifact org.apache.maven:maven-plugin-api:jar:2.0.9 from/to central
```

Any idea why this error

Answer (score 0):

Seems very similar with this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21721357/error-in-pom-xml-maven-build). As suggested in the answer of the linked question  try the -U switch.

Of course assuming that STS has properly configured Maven (either the build one or the one configured in your machine).