# TypeNotPresentException , Maven Project Build Lifecycle Mapping Problem exceptions while performing maven build

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, maven-plugin

I'm trying to perform clean build for maven project and got below errors.

> **Error 1:**

```
CoreException: Could not get the value for parameter compilerId for plugin execution default-compile: TypeNotPresentException: Type org.apache.maven.plugin.compiler.CompilerMojo not present   pom.xml /ETMFramework   line 19 Maven Project Build Lifecycle Mapping Problem
```

> **Error 2:**

```
Plugin execution not covered by lifecycle configuration: org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.0:testCompile (execution: default-testCompile, phase: test-compile) pom.xml /ETMFramework   line 19 Maven Project Build Lifecycle Mapping Problem
```

**Eclipse version:** Version: Neon.3 (4.6.3)

Below is the POM.XML I'm using

> **POM.XML**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>----group name---</groupId>
<artifactId>automationFramework</artifactId>
<version>2.12.2</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>
<distributionManagement>
    <repository>
        <id>central</id>
        <name>eftaf-maven-release-local/</name>
        <url>-----artifactory URL-----</url>
    </repository>
</distributionManagement>
<build>
    <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
    <finalName>${project.artifactId}</finalName>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-source-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.1</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>attach-sources</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>jar</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0-M1</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.1</version>
            <configuration>

                <archive>

                    <manifestFile>${basedir}/MANIFEST.MF</manifestFile>
                </archive>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.1</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>copy-dependencies</id>
                    <phase>prepare-package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <stripVersion>true</stripVersion>
                        <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/lib</outputDirectory>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>copy-resources</id>
                    <phase>process-resources</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>copy-resources</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}</outputDirectory>
                        <resources>
                            <resource>
                                <directory>${project.basedir}</directory>
                                <includes>
                                    <include>chromedriver.exe</include>
                                    <include>geckodriver.exe</include>
                                    <include>IEDriverServer.exe</include>
                                    <include>MicrosoftWebDriver.exe</include>
                                    <include>JdbcOdbc.dll</include>
                                    <include>com4j-x86.dll</include>
                                    <include>sqljdbc_auth.dll</include>
                                    <include>sqljdbc_xa.dll</include>
                                    <include>Execute Command Line.bat</include>
                                </includes>
                            </resource>
                        </resources>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.jcraft</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsch</artifactId>
        <version>0.1.55</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
        <artifactId>mssql-jdbc</artifactId>
        <version>7.0.0.jre8</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.ibm.db2.jcc</groupId>
        <artifactId>db2jcc4</artifactId>
        <version>11.1.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.oracle.jdbc</groupId>
        <artifactId>ojdbc8</artifactId>
        <version>12.2.0.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver</groupId>
        <artifactId>jdbc</artifactId>
        <version>7.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.codoid.products</groupId>
        <artifactId>fillo</artifactId>
        <version>1.18</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
        <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
        <version>4.5.6</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.opencsv</groupId>
        <artifactId>opencsv</artifactId>
        <version>4.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
        <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
        <version>6.10</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.12.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.aventstack</groupId>
        <artifactId>extentreports</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.9</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.jayway.jsonpath</groupId>
        <artifactId>json-path</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.pdfbox</groupId>
        <artifactId>pdfbox</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.12</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jvnet.com4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>com4j</artifactId>
        <version>2.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
        <version>${SeleniumVersion}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.mail</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.mail</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.swt</groupId>
        <artifactId>org.eclipse.swt.win32.win32.x86</artifactId>
        <version>4.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.appium</groupId>
        <artifactId>java-client</artifactId>
        <version>${AppiumVersion}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.github.2gis.winium</groupId>
        <artifactId>winium-webdriver</artifactId>
        <version>0.1.0-1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.github.2gis.winium</groupId>
        <artifactId>winium-elements-desktop</artifactId>
        <version>0.2.0-1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.ant</groupId>
        <artifactId>ant</artifactId>
        <version>1.10.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-ant-tasks</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
        <version>2.6</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        <version>1.18.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-server</artifactId>
        <version>${SeleniumVersion}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
        <artifactId>mongo-java-driver</artifactId>
        <version>3.10.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.xml.stream</groupId>
        <artifactId>stax-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.0-2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sikulix</groupId>
        <artifactId>sikulixapi</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.json/json -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.json</groupId>
        <artifactId>json</artifactId>
        <version>20190722</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
<properties>
    <SeleniumVersion>3.141.59</SeleniumVersion>
    <AppiumVersion>7.2.0</AppiumVersion>
</properties>
```

I have tried updating the maven project update, deleting the .m2 local repository solutions but they did not resolved the errors.

Kindly check on these errors and share any solutions, if any of you have encountered these before. Thanks a ton in advance!!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38992091/9634563  have you tried this??

Comment: @Ajay- I did applied the solution mentioned above, it did not resolved the errors. I have tried using [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5074063/maven-error-failure-to-transfer) solution as well